# Using navigation properties in linq query throws error if foreign keys are null

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

```
 var devSum = repository.Devices
            .Where(dev => dev.Id == deviceId)
            .SingleOrDefault();
        vmDeviceSummary result = new vmDeviceSummary
        {
          DeviceId = deviceId,

          DeviceName = devSum.Name,
          MacAddress = devSum.MacAddress,
          DeviceType = devSum.DeviceType.Name,
          Enabled = devSum.Enabled.ToString(),
          ConfigurationLoaded = devSum.ConfigurationLoaded.ToString(),
          AllowReload = devSum.AllowDataReload.ToString(),
          DataGroup = devSum.DataGroup.Name,
          ManagementGroup = devSum.ManagementGroup.Name,
        };
```

I thought this should work, but it throws an error if there is a null in the foreign key in the link to the datagoups or managementGroup entities.

How do i work around this so it would act like an outer join and return null?

Comment: If the related DataGroup of ManagementGroup object (record) simple isn't there, then Linq cannot provide the object (or an empty object) for you. You will have to fill it in yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can get a little ugly, but you can do this with a ternary operator:

```
DeviceType = devSum.DeviceType != null ? devSum.DeviceType.Name : null,
```

Comment: Aye, but I wanted to avoid that, surely linq can do this.

Comment: Nope, sorry, this is pretty much it. You're always responsible for checking for nulls.

Comment: I appreciate you're help Grant but just because neither of us knows the answer doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: @DavidB I'm not saying I don't know, I'm saying I know the answer: it's "no".

Comment: Lol ok fair enough. I'll go with this. Seems strange though.

Answer (score 0):

Change the above code with this

```
var devSum = repository.Devices .Where(dev => dev.Id == deviceId) .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need to do an `Include`

```
var devSum = repository.Devices
            .Include("DeviceType")
            .Include("ManagementGroup")
            .Where(dev => dev.Id == deviceId)
            .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Then you have to go with Grant Thomas's answer. If the relation is collection, out can use the `DefaultIfEmpty()` and it would be en equivalent of an outer join.

Comment: Thanks, Ill check out defaultIfEmpty